# FFMPEG- Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0][1]xfade

Tags: ffmpeg

Please help me fixing the error:

```
ffmpeg -i video_3044.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=314.74,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart video_5370_1.mp4'
```

Error:

```
Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:dura
tion=0.5:offset=314.74,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c
2=tri[audio].
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have 1 input: [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) filter requires 2 inputs.

```
ffmpeg -i video_3044.mp4 -i video_3045.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=314.74,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart video_5370_1.mp4
```